# Creating new rows with missing month & year and corresponding values as Zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have extracted details using group by on months. But unfortunately, if the data is not present in the months, **no record is created for that month**.

Please help me to create new records for each of the company where data range starts from 2019 April annd ends at 2020 February.

```
Company     year    month   Quantity
A           2019    4          1
A           2019    5          12
A           2019    6          13
A           2019    11         23
A           2020    2          34
B           2019    8          32
B           2019    12         2
B           2020    2          32
```

**Exactly in the below format. Any inputs can be a great help.**

```
Company     year    month   Quantity
A           2019    1          0
A           2019    2          0
A           2019    3          0
A           2019    4          0
A           2019    5          12
A           2019    6          13
A           2019    7          0
A           2019    8          0
A           2019    9          0
A           2019    10         0
A           2019    11         23
A           2019    12         0
A           2020    1          0
A           2020    2          34
B           2019    1          0
B           2019    2          0
B           2019    3          0
B           2019    4          0
B           2019    5          0
B           2019    6          0
B           2019    7          0
B           2019    8          32
B           2019    9          0
B           2019    10         0
B           2019    11         0
B           2019    12         2
B           2020    1          0
B           2020    2          32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want full months use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Company'].unique(),
                                  df['year'].unique(),
                                  range(1, 13)], names=['Company','year','month'])

df = df.set_index(['Company','year','month']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

If necessary filter out by minimal and maximal datetimes by original data use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) by maximal and minimal datetimes:

```
orig = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month']].assign(day=1))
new = pd.to_datetime(df1[['year','month']].assign(day=1))

df1 = df1[new.between(orig.min(), orig.max())]
print (df1)
   Company  year  month  Quantity
3        A  2019      4         1
4        A  2019      5        12
5        A  2019      6        13
6        A  2019      7         0
7        A  2019      8         0
8        A  2019      9         0
9        A  2019     10         0
10       A  2019     11        23
11       A  2019     12         0
12       A  2020      1         0
13       A  2020      2        34
27       B  2019      4         0
28       B  2019      5         0
29       B  2019      6         0
30       B  2019      7         0
31       B  2019      8        32
32       B  2019      9         0
33       B  2019     10         0
34       B  2019     11         0
35       B  2019     12         2
36       B  2020      1         0
37       B  2020      2        32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date range containing all the months, then reindex the dataframe:

```
# `all_date` contains every month start from min to max
date = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month']].assign(day=1))
all_date = pd.date_range(month.min(), month.max(), freq='MS')

# the new_index has every combination of (Company, month start)
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    df['Company'].unique(),
    all_date
], names=['Company', 'date'])

# Reindex and filling the NAs
result = df.set_index(['Company', date]).reindex(new_index).reset_index()
result['year'] = result['date'].dt.year
result['month'] = result['date'].dt.month
result['Quantity'] = result['Quantity'].fillna(0)
```

**Tip:** do not split a date into `year` and `month`. A date is often easier to analyze if you keep it as a `Timestamp` instead of splitting out its components.